# How to increase a counter whilst a key is pressed in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, counter

I am creating an app that turns a sphere which is the earth when w is pressed to speed it up and s is used to slow it down. However I am unable how to find out how to make the speed increase. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Spin : MonoBehaviour{

public float speed;

void Update ()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) {
        Application.Quit();
    }
    if (Input.GetKey ("w")) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,speed + 1);

    }
    if (Input.GetKey ("s")) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,speed - 1);

    }
}
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can increase the speed for how long the button is pressed?

P.S I wish to write in c#

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my lack of knowledge with Unity, but it looks like your if statements don't update the value of `speed`. As it is now, if the key is pressed, you are only rotating at the value of `speed + 1`. But speed is never changed.

Maybe try something like this?

```
if (Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed + 1);
    speed++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Update ()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) {
        Application.Quit();
    }
    if (Input.GetKey ("w")) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,speed++);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey ("s")) {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up,speed--);
    }
}
```

If you use `speed++` it will use the `speed` as paramater for your `transform.Rotate` method and **only then** will increment it by **1**.

If you, on the other hand, use `++speed`, it will **first** increment it and then be used as parameter.

Same applies for `speed--` and `--speed`.

Comment: Good answer, and it is apparent that the OP doesn't know what this does or he would have used it. As explanation, `speed++` is the same as `speed += 1`. It is a reassignment with an increment.

Comment: `speed++` might not be a good idea sinc the time between two frames is not fixed

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a kind of acceleration. Remember that `Update` is called on each frame and that the framerate varies.

So, add an `acceleration` field in your script. Then increase the speed by the amount of acceleration times the `deltaTime` between two frames.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    // calculate new speed
    if (Input.GetKey ("w")) {
        speed += acceleration*Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey ("s")) {
        speed -= acceleration*Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // apply speed
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed*Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Note that since you are using this speed for a rotation, the unit of `speed` is degree/s and the unit of `acceleration` is degree/(s^2).